# RuntimeError: cublas runtime error : resource allocation failed

Tags: python-3.x, neural-network, deep-learning, pytorch

I tried to run this simple model. Basically this model is for text classification. I have used random word embeddings.

```
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

class DSC_RE(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim, embedding_dim, output_dim):

        super().__init__()

        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(input_dim, embedding_dim)

        self.fc = nn.Linear(embedding_dim, output_dim)

    def forward(self, text):

        #text = [batch size, sent len]

        text=torch.t(text)

        #text = [sent len, batch size]

        embed = self.embedding(text)

        #embed = [sent len, batch size, embedding dim]

        embed = embed.permute(1,2,0)

        #embed = [batch size, embedding dim, sent len]

        output = F.max_pool1d(embed, embed.size(2))

        #output = [batch size, embedding dim,1]

        output = output.squeeze(2)

        #output = [batch size, embedding dim]

        return self.fc(output)
```

However, I got this error when I ran the code

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-d82622e3ea00> in <module>()
      1 n_epochs=20
----> 2 run_model(model,train_dataloader, test_dataloader,optimizer,criterion,n_epochs)

6 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in linear(input, weight, bias)
   1368     if input.dim() == 2 and bias is not None:
   1369         # fused op is marginally faster
-> 1370         ret = torch.addmm(bias, input, weight.t())
   1371     else:
   1372         output = input.matmul(weight.t())

RuntimeError: cublas runtime error : resource allocation failed at /pytorch/aten/src/THC/THCGeneral.cpp:216
```

Any help is really appreciated..............

I ran this code in Google Colab using Tesla K80 GPU and Pytorch 1.x version

Comment: What is your batch size, length of your sequences, and the embedding dimension? The error is basically telling you that you are running out of memory, so decreasing the batch size should fix the issue.

Comment: batch size is 16, maximum length of sequence is 32 and embedding dimension=100. Even though I have used small values for all these, this error is coming. @dennlinger

Comment: Did you solve this @KalyanKatikapalli ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't.